SQLite slow combined query from two fast SELECT queries
Select join query with FTS table is slow if other WHERE conditions are specified. But these WHERE conditions without fts MATCH condition are not slow and fts MATCH is not slow alone. How to combine MATCH condition and other WHERE conditions without slowing down the query
posts table has 100,000 rows, posts.deleted_at and posts.root_id columns have indexes created and posts_fts table is created using sqlite fts5 extension.
SQLite 3 version is 3.40.
Query 1 is fast. Query finished in 0.078 second(s).
SELECT count(posts.id) AS count FROM posts 
WHERE posts.deleted_at IS NULL AND posts.root_id IN (12)

--
Query 2 is fast. Query finished in 0.003 second(s).
SELECT count(posts.id) as count FROM posts 
JOIN posts_fts on posts.id = posts_fts.rowid 
WHERE posts_fts match 'aqua* avai*'

--
But this combined query is slow. Query finished in 6.783 second(s).
SELECT count(posts.id) AS count FROM posts 
JOIN posts_fts ON posts.id = posts_fts.rowid 
WHERE posts.root_id IN (12) AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL 
 AND posts_fts MATCH 'aqua* avai*'

--
This alternate version is slow too. Query finished in 6.835 second(s).
SELECT count(posts.id) AS count FROM posts 
JOIN 
 (SELECT rowid AS id, rank FROM posts_fts WHERE posts_fts MATCH 'aqua* avai*') fts 
 ON fts.id = posts.id 
WHERE posts.root_id IN (12) AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL

--
But this version is fast. Query finished in 0.002 second(s).
SELECT count(posts.id) AS count FROM posts 
WHERE posts.id IN 
 (SELECT rowid FROM posts_fts WHERE posts_fts MATCH 'aqua* avai*') 
 AND posts.root_id IN (12) AND posts.deleted_at IS NULL

But with this version, I am unable to use rank from fts table correctly.
I need to join with posts_fts table to use rank in ORDER BY clause
Please tell me how to speed up the combined query

Here the combined query is slow because of index created on posts.root_id column. I removed this index and now the Query finished in 0.003 second(s). posts.root_id column have only 10 distinct values which are not enough to use an index correctly. Incorrect index combined with a join query were causing slow query.
More info here:
performance - Why is this sqlite query much slower when I index the columns? - Database Administrators Stack Exchange
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150858/why-is-this-sqlite-query-much-slower-when-i-index-the-columns
sql - Very slow queries in a large database even with indexes - Stack Overflow
Very slow queries in a large database even with indexes
